# Silverstripe DropdownField does not respect default value argument

Tags: silverstripe

Pretty simple question, I'm creating a dropdown field and trying to set the selected value like so:

```
$tourField = DropdownField::create('Tour', 'Tour', Tour::get()->sort('TourName ASC')->map('ID', 'TourName')->toArray(), $currentTourID);
```

I have confirmed that $currentTourID contains the correct value (a numeric ID) and that value exists in the resulting dropdown. When rendered, no item in the dropdown is selected by default. So I assume I have something else wrong here.

**Edit:** Note that this field is a has_one relationship field with the object, and in the case of this object, the value of it is null. I am trying to override that and set it using something a bit smarter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My edit made me realise that all I had to do was set the object representation of these fields rather than try to manually override the default value. The key here is that the dropdowns in question reference a relationship in the object.

So instead of:

```
$currentTourID = $mySmartFunction();
$tourField = DropdownField::create('TourID', 'Tour', Tour::get()->sort('TourName ASC')->map('ID', 'TourName')->toArray(), $currentTourID);
```

I did this:

```
$this->TourID = $mySmartFunction();
$tourField = DropdownField::create('TourID', 'Tour', Tour::get()->sort('TourName ASC')->map('ID', 'TourName')->toArray());
```

Comment: If that worked, please set your own answer as the accepted one :)